# Connect to Exchange email with windows authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, exchange-server

Its possible to connect to Exchange email box with windows authentication ? I cant have password in the program because of security compliance. If yes, how? Thank you.

### working solution

- download: EWS Management API 2.1
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42022
- add assembly to reference: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web
  Services\2.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
- switch project to .NET framework 3.5 (im not really sure if this is a must)

#### code

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.AutodiscoverUrl("username@domain.tld");
```

Comment: You can probably use something like UseDefaultCredentials which will use for authentication the user that is logged in. This depends a bit on what are you trying to do: send emails, read emails, etc.

Comment: Thank you i will try it, i need to download attachment of last received email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [ExchangeServiceBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/exchangewebservices.exchangeservicebinding(v=exchg.150).aspx) class from Exchange Web Services you have [UseDefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms152953) property. Setting this to true will make the authentication use the current user.